# Where should I ask questions about Transifex?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, localization

The [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/) translation system is used for localization of Stack Exchange sites. Is there a site in the Stack Exchange network where I could ask questions about this system?

I’m going to ask questions about using Transifex in general, not related to SE.

Comment: Really depends what you want to ask about it. If it's something about the way SE use it, then this is the right place. If about how the site works in general, there is [already a tag on Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transifex).

Comment: @ShadowWizard that should probably be an answer, not a comment

Comment: @ShadowWizard clarified the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Coding questions presumably belong on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transifex); other questions can go to [Webapps.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transifex).**

Stack Overflow will naturally take programming questions relating to the service.

But it appears that Webapps.SE will take other Transifex questions; looking through their [[transifex]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transifex) tag, it appears that general questions about the service are allowed, such as [*Username change on Transifex*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40095/144998) and [*How do you do a Transifex text search with an “or” operator?*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/75675/144998). So, if you have a *general* question about Transifex, it should go to Webapps.SE; if you have a *programming* question relating to Transifex, it should go to Stack Overflow.