# User name autocomplete (with @) not working in mobile version

Tags: feature-request, bug, comments, mobile-web, autocomplete

If I

- open any post on any Stack Exchange site in mobile version (Chrome 63 on Android)
- then click "add a comment"
- then type `@`
- then type first letter of user name which already commented to this post

Then no username autocomplete happens.

Here is gif where I try to autocomplete `@Mureinik` in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305003/359876):

> [image]

In desktop Chrome autocomplete works as expected (that is after typing `@` and first letter of username, popup with username appears):

> [image]

Sorry if this question is duplicate.

I don't know exactly why this is not a bug (@iDebug says so), so I put both [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) labels.

Comment: This is not a bug. It's not implemented on mobile.

Comment: @iDebug can you say please, so i should change label to [tag:feature-request]?

Comment: Probably should.